# TeamCity Setting up MSTest 2012

Tags: teamcity, build-automation, mstest

On the TeamCity server we have installed VS 2012.

I have created a build configuration in TeamCity that builds and deploys the solution.

I have added a MSTest 2012 Configuration as well, but don't know how to tell it what project is the VS 2012 test project so that it can run those tests.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to specify assembly file (dll) of your tests, not the project file (csproj).

Here's an example: http://shrani.si/f/p/PH/2tO4Zo5s/tmpa4cc.jpg
[image]

So let's say your Testing assembly is called Company.Tests.dll and it is located in Company.Tests/bin/Debug/Company.Tests.dll

Basically, in "List assembly files:" you must put the path (You can use wildcards)

For example:

```
**\bin\**\*.Tests.dll
```

This will locate all assemblies with .Tests.dll suffix.

Regards