# How to run Visual Studio 2012 tests on TeamCity 7.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, teamcity-7.1

For Visual Studio 2012 solutions I have previously been using the *MSTest 2010* option with a *.testsettings* file without any problems on TeamCity 7.1. However since this is now outdated I would like to use the new *.runsettings* file.

I see that you can use *MSTest 2012* in TeamCity, but when I try to set this up, nothing gets saved. I have set the assemblies to include ( e.g. `%ROOTBUILDPATH%\Tests\bin\Release\Tests.dll`), but have set nothing else such as the *results file*. I haven't specified the *results file* as there doesn't seem to be any *.trx* output in my *TestResults* folder with 2012.

I have seen [TeamCity Setting up MSTest 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408166/teamcity-setting-up-mstest-2012) , but the screenshot is cropped and I don't know what to configure on the rest of the page.

Do I actually need to create a *.runsettings* (currently using the MS [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx))? How can I get TeamCity to run my 2012 tests with the minimal amount of configuration?